# Exclude nested subdocuments in Mongodb without arrays

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Here is how data are inserted in a "Products" MongoDB collection (using Meteor):

```
Products.insert(
{
    productOne:
    {
        publicData:
        {
            pricePerUnit : 1,
            label : "The first product"
        },
        privateData:
        {
            test1: "xxxxx",
            test2: "xxxxx"
        }
    },
    productTwo:
    {
        publicData:
        {
            pricePerUnit : 2,
            label : "The second product"
        },
        privateData:
        {
            test1: "yyyyy",
            test2: "yyyyy"
        }
    }
}
);
```

I would like to retrieve all the products, but without the "privateData" subdocuments, to get this:

```
{
    productOne:
    {
        publicData:
        {
            pricePerUnit : 1,
            label : "The first product"
        }
    },
    productTwo:
    {
        publicData:
        {
            pricePerUnit : 2,
            label : "The second product"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried several things with "$elemMatch" but honnestly I didn't succeed in anything, I have trouble understanding how I am even supposed to do that.

Would anyone have a suggestion? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Query would be something Similar to this

```
Products.find({},{
        fields: {
            privateData: 0
        }
    }
```

`privateData:0` will make sure that the field is omitted.

please Refer https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/ for more info

Answer (score -1):

if you can use the aggregation framework you can use the `$project` operator:

```
db.<colletion_name>.aggregate( { $project: { publicData: 1} } );
```

And you will get back all of your documents with only the `publicData` field

Comment: But this is different from what they're asking. They want to exclude `privateData`, they don't want to retrieve _only_ `publicData`.

Comment: yes, but the result is the same, as you can project every field you want, and get the result without the filed you don't project

Comment: The result _at this point in time_ is the same. What if another set of fields is added at the same level as `publicData` and `privateData`? Then your solution would hide the new set of fields erroneously. Sorry, but this is not the right solution. The goal of the OP is: "I would like to retrieve all the products, but without the "privateData" subdocuments." Your solution is: "Show only the publicData subdocuments."

Comment: @ffxsam: i've posted a solution for the data the OP has given. If another set of fields would be added to the documents you could project them too (btw: i don't think the answer deserves even a downvote: i understand that there may be better ways to achieve this, but my solution provides the right output in respect to the question )